# IOS6 web app - Home screen application not refreshing

Tags: caching, web-applications, geolocation, ios6, homescreen

I'm writing this in regard to the infamous problem with IOS 6 where geolocation in web apps break oftenly. The only solution was to remove the
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`
line from the index which solves this issue as it causes the web application to be a regular browser application. The problem i've encountered is that even with this solution, all currently installed Home screen applications still don't work (use the old index) and only when installing the web app again in the home screen the solution works.
What exactly is the problem here? is the previous home screen apps cache the index? is there a way to solve this?

Thanks